# Android Studio - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a massive problem on my project.

I uploaded 18 photos to the project and since then this error started.

I tried looking for a solution but it didnt help.

**I found dexOptions { 
          incremental true 
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}**

Since it seems it worked for most people I wonder if I wrote it in the correct spot.

**I tried to write it on my gradle build but it kept asking me for a plugin.**

I would be greatful if someone can help me please.

**Added the log.**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 111314956 byte allocation with 12232500 free bytes and 78MB until OOM
                                                   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                                                   at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
                                                   at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:59)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:55)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                   at childernsapp.raz.com.learning.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**My on click code I didnt finish it because it crashes all the time**

```
   ImageButton oneBtn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.One);
    oneBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton twoBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Two);
    twoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton threeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Three);
    threeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton fourBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Four);
    fourBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton fiveBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Five);
    fiveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton sixBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Sixth);
    sixBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton sevenBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Seven);
    sevenBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton eightBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Eight);
    eightBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton nineBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Nine);
    nineBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView myImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myNum);

    if (v.getId() == R.id.One)
    {
        myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    }
```

**My XML**`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Two"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/numtwo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Three"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/numthree"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Two"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/myNum"
    android:contentDescription="myImg"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Four"
    android:src="@drawable/numfour"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/One"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Five"
    android:layout_below="@+id/One"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/numfive"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Sixth"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Five"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Three"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Three"
    android:src="@drawable/numsixth"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Seven"
    android:layout_above="@+id/myNum"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/numseven"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Eight"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Seven"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/numeight"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Nine"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Eight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Sixth"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Sixth"
    android:src="@drawable/numnine"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

`

Comment: Please add the locat.

Comment: wait, do you have an issue with android-studio or android-app?

Comment: Bro.. 18 images shouldt crash your app.. What are these images sizes? How and where are you using them?

Comment: I am having a problem with my app.All the photos weight 1.05mb.I use half of them as a ImageButton.Then I have Bas a ImageView,therefore when they click on one of the ImageButtons one of the other half photos pops on the ImageView. Basically You have 10 photos that should display on the screen.

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 111314956 byte allocation with 12226730 free bytes and 78MB until OOM
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)

Comment: show your layout and activity, where you use the photos

Comment: I put onClickListner on the ImageButtons and I have 1 ImageView. Then on the OnClick method I did IF (v.getId == X) SetImageRes....

Comment: man, 1mb as a imagebutton its too much. You need you resize it. Or try to create a drawable-nodpi folder and put your images inside it

Comment: No man I got 18 photos that all combained weight about 1mb.

Comment: I had a photo that weight 400kb. I deleted it and still not working. now my total is 550kb.

Comment: you should post your onclick code and your layout, otherwise we only can guess what can be issue... What if you try it with only 1 imageButton?

Comment: Added everything in the post.

Comment: I think you should rework your layout and put your image-buttons into a `ListView`. That way the Images, that are not on screen will be removed from memory. Btw, whats about having only 1 ImageButton on screen? Can your App handle this?

Comment: @JohnnyAW what do you mean ? all my imagebuttons are shown on the screen and I need it to be on the screen

Comment: imagine you need to show 1000000 images in your app, how would you do this? You would put them into a `ListView`, `ListView` on the other hand makes sure, that rows, that are not visible on the screen while you scroll down, will be utilized and removed from memory. I assume that your photos have quite big resolution, so 1 Image should be able to fill your screen, thats why you should put them into a `ListView`, that will handle memory while you scroll up and down

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
AndroidManifest.xml
```

android:largeHeap="true"
application

Comment: App is up now but when I press my imagebutton it shows blackscreen.

Comment: Tried to switch to other photo again does outofmemory error.

Comment: <activity android:name=".BizForum.ArticleFullView">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".DashBoard.GlobalLinker" />
        </activity>ImageButton backpage  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        backpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(ArticleFullView.this);
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageButton backpage  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
    backpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(ArticleFullView.this);
        }
    });
```

manifest

```
  <activity android:name=".BizForum.ArticleFullView">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".DashBoard.GlobalLinker" />
    </activity>
```